# Allowed characters for CSS identifiers

Tags: css, regex, validation

What are the (full) valid / allowed <strike>charset</strike> characters for CSS identifiers `id` and `class`?

Is there a regular expression that I can use to validate against? Is it browser agnostic?

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of s.o. Q448981: [What characters are valid in CSS class names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What characters are valid in CSS class names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names)

Comment: @mercator: Also voting to close. =)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The charset doesn't matter. The allowed characters matters more. Check the [CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters). Here's a cite of relevance:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in [selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)) can contain only the characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and ISO 10646 characters `U+00A0` and higher, plus the hyphen (`-`) and the underscore (`_`); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier `"B&W?"` may be written as `"B\&W\?"` or `"B\26 W\3F"`.

**Update**: As to the regex question, you can find the grammar [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner):

```
ident      -?{nmstart}{nmchar}*
```

Which contains of the parts:

```
nmstart    [_a-z]|{nonascii}|{escape}
nmchar     [_a-z0-9-]|{nonascii}|{escape}
nonascii   [\240-\377]
escape     {unicode}|\\[^\r\n\f0-9a-f]
unicode    \\{h}{1,6}(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?
h          [0-9a-f]
```

This can be translated to a Java regex as follows (I only added parentheses to parts containing the OR and escaped the backslashes):

```
String h = "[0-9a-f]";
String unicode = "\\\\{h}{1,6}(\\r\\n|[ \\t\\r\\n\\f])?".replace("{h}", h);
String escape = "({unicode}|\\\\[^\\r\\n\\f0-9a-f])".replace("{unicode}", unicode);
String nonascii = "[\\240-\\377]";
String nmchar = "([_a-z0-9-]|{nonascii}|{escape})".replace("{nonascii}", nonascii).replace("{escape}", escape);
String nmstart = "([_a-z]|{nonascii}|{escape})".replace("{nonascii}", nonascii).replace("{escape}", escape);
String ident = "-?{nmstart}{nmchar}*".replace("{nmstart}", nmstart).replace("{nmchar}", nmchar);

System.out.println(ident); // The full regex.
```

**Update 2**: oh, you're more a PHP'er, well I think you can figure how/where to do `str_replace`?

Comment: "the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F"" - But nobody does that, and I'm glad they don't. :-)

Comment: THANK YOU! That's just awesome! :D I though it was very limited but didn't knew I could use `\` as an escape character. Has anyone ever built a regex to validate the allowed chars?

Comment: That's perfect, and yes I can figure it out. =) Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to make it case insensitive or to lowercase the identifier beforehand.

Comment: If I evaluate your Java, I get the following regex pattern:
`-?([_a-z]|[\x200-\x377]|(\\[0-9a-f]{1,6}(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\[^\r\n\f0-9a-f]))([_a-z0-9-]|[\x200-\x377]|(\\[0-9a-f]{1,6}(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\[^\r\n\f0-9a-f])
)*`

Yet that matches the string "2thisshouldfail" which is not a valid CSS indicator

Comment: @BalusC `[\200-\377]` indicates an OCTAL base. it is not clear why  you mention =\200-\377 where it says \240-\377. NAd it is certainly not the value  `\\x200` which represents hex.

Comment: @AnthonyMcLin His regex is wrong. you are right. see [here](http://i.imgur.com/GZXKldE.png)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for something a little more turn-key.  The full expression, replaced and all, from @BalusC's answer is:

```
/-?([_a-z]|[\240-\377]|([0-9a-f]{1,6}(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|[^\r\n\f0-9a-f]))([_a-z0-9-]|[\240-\377]|([0-9a-f]{1,6}(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|[^\r\n\f0-9a-f]))*/
```

And using `DEFINE`, which I find a little more readable:

```
/(?(DEFINE)
    (?P<h>        [0-9a-f]                             )
    (?P<unicode>  (?&h){1,6}(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?        )
    (?P<escape>   ((?&unicode)|[^\r\n\f0-9a-f])*       )
    (?P<nonascii> [\240-\377]                          )
    (?P<nmchar>   ([_a-z0-9-]|(?&nonascii)|(?&escape)) )
    (?P<nmstart>  ([_a-z]|(?&nonascii)|(?&escape))     )
    (?P<ident>    -?(?&nmstart)(?&nmchar)*             )
) (?:
    (?&ident)
)/x
```

Incidentally, the original regular expression (and @human's contribution) had a few rogue escape characters that allow `[` in the name.

Also, it should be noted that the raw regex without, `DEFINE`, runs about 2x as fast as the `DEFINE` expression, taking only ~23 steps to identify a single unicode character, while the later takes ~40.

Answer (score 2):

This is merely a contribution to @BalusC answer. It is the PHP version of the Java code he provided, I converted it and I thought someone else could find it helpful.

```
$h = "[0-9a-f]";
$unicode = str_replace( "{h}", $h, "\{h}{1,6}(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?" );
$escape = str_replace( "{unicode}", $unicode, "({unicode}|\[^\r\n\f0-9a-f])");
$nonascii = "[\240-\377]";
$nmchar = str_replace( array( "{nonascii}", "{escape}" ), array( $nonascii, $escape ), "([_a-z0-9-]|{nonascii}|{escape})");
$nmstart = str_replace( array( "{nonascii}", "{escape}" ), array( $nonascii, $escape ), "([_a-z]|{nonascii}|{escape})" );
$ident = str_replace( array( "{nmstart}", "{nmchar}" ), array( $nmstart, $nmchar ), "-?{nmstart}{nmchar}*");


echo $ident; // The full regex.
```