# Display classes of which exists in an string of number

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, addclass

I have this string of numbers `var array = 1,6,2,9,5` which is retrieved from an API so I can really change the way it is.

and I have this in my html:

```
<div class="1 btn">Foo 1</div>
<div class="2 btn">Foo 2</div>
<div class="3 btn">Foo 3</div>
<div class="4 btn">Foo 4</div>
<div class="5 btn">Foo 5</div>
<div class="6 btn">Foo 6</div>
<div class="7 btn">Foo 7</div>
<div class="8 btn">Foo 8</div>
<div class="9 btn">Foo 9</div>
```

I want to add on any class that exists into the array a class '`foo`'. So in my example div's 1,6,2,9,5 will get a class '`foo`'.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is that `1,6,2,9,5` a string?

Comment: Probably it should be `[1, 6, 2, 9, 5]`.  People do themselves no favors with broken sample code in their questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick way:

```
$('.' + array.join(', .')).addClass('foo');
```

*edit* — if the "array" is actually a string:

```
$('.' + array.split(',').join(', .')).addClass('foo');
```

Comment: Thank you. I just mentioned that it is not an array but a string since I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object 1,6,2,9,5 has no method 'join'

Comment: OK, well as I said it's important to be accurate in your questions :-)

Comment: @Pointy I dont know why I thought it was an array. At least know I will take extra care when asking any questions. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that jQuery will allow you multiple selectors separated by commas, which is pretty close to what you already have:

If `array` is really an array:

```
$("." + array.join(", .")).addClass("foo");
```

If it's a string (e.g. `"1,2,3"`) instead:

```
$("." + array.replace(/,/g, ", .")).addClass("foo");
```

Comment: Thank you. I was wrong on my question and it is a string. When I used your second option, only the first 2 strings get the class. When I use console.log(array.replace(",", ", ."); I get 1, .6,2,9,5

Comment: @jQuerybeast: That was a mistake on my part (I always keep forgetting how `replace` does not replace all occurrences unless you feed it a regex as the first parameter). Edited the answer to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    $('.' + array[i]).addClass('foo');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES5 `.some`: http://jsfiddle.net/rkknp/1/.

```
var array = [1, 6, 2, 9, 5];

// filter elements that have a class apparent in the array
$(".btn").filter(function() {
    return array.some( $.fn.hasClass.bind( $(this) ) );
}).addClass("red");​
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using invalid names for your CSS classes.

> The name can contain characters a-z, A-Z, digits 0-9, period, hyphen, escaped characters, Unicode characters 161-255, as well as any Unicode character as a numeric code, however, they cannot start with a dash or a digit.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters, [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names) and [Allowed characters for CSS identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812072/allowed-characters-for-css-identifiers).

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Note that I'm using jQuery in this code

```
var yourArray = [1,6,2,9,5];
var elements = $('div');

for(var i=0; i<yourArray.length; i++){
    $(elements[yourArray[i]-1]).addClass('foo');
}
```