# what is this type of CSS code?

Tags: html, css

this is a html code in a webpage:

```
<div class="3u">

...

</div>
```

It styled with css in this way:

```
.\33 u, .\33 u\24, .\33 u\28 1\29, .\33 u\24\28 1\29 { width: 25%; clear: none; }
```

Can anybody explain me what is this?

I familar with CSS but Not this type!

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043347/css-css-coding-that-i-have-never-seen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You technically can't start a CSS selector with a number. However, you can use escape characters to get around that it looks like. [Check this out](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes).

> Leading digits
>
> If the first character of an identifier is numeric, you’ll need to
>   escape it based on its Unicode code point. For example, the code point
>   for the character 1 is U+0031, so you would escape it as \000031 or
>   \31 .
>
> Basically, to escape any numeric character, just prefix it with \3 and
>   append a space character ( ). Yay Unicode!

Comment: Hence my first sentence...

Comment: Thanks... so for 33u it becomes "/33 u".....but what is ".\33 u\24"?

Comment: I know, I was just trying to emphasize it a bit.