# How to align box in a row

Tags: html, css, alignment

Here is what I have now :

[image]

But I want something more like this :

[image]

So here is my code :

HTML :

```
    <div class = "gros_box">    <!-- gros box -->

    <div class = "titre_num_serie"> N° Serie : 
    </div> <!-- end titre n° serie -->

    <div class = "model_box"> Info Basic : 
    </div> <!-- end model box -->

    <div class = "compo_box"> Composant : 
    </div> <!-- end compo box -->

    <div class = "autre_box"> Autres Info : 
    </div> <!-- end autre info -->

</div> <!-- end du gros box -->
```

CSS :

```
.gros_box{
padding-top : 20px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 50px;

/*width: 850px;*/
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;
}

.titre_num_serie{

padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 10px;
padding-left : 10px;
padding-bottom : 10px;

width: 200px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin:0 auto;

text-align : center;

}

.model_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;

width: 350px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;
}

.compo_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;

width: 350px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;
}

.autre_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;

width: 350px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;
}
```

I tried also to put the 3 boxes in a span, tried with a inline, tried to play with the width/margin/padding but I can't really get what I'm looking for :/

**EDIT**
**My Solution**

```
.gros_box{
padding-top : 20px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 50px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;
}

.titre_num_serie{

padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 10px;
padding-left : 10px;
padding-bottom : 10px;
width: 200px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin:0 auto;
text-align : center;

}

.model_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;
width: 25%;
height : 350px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;

}

.compo_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;
width: 30%;
height : 350px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;

}

.autre_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;
width: 25%;
height : 350px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;

}

.model_box ,.compo_box,.autre_box{display: inline-block;}
.autre_box{margin-right: 0;}
```

Comment: You could `float` them, `left` `center` and `right`

Comment: I would look up flexbox, if you don't need great browser support.

Comment: I wouldn't use the `°` in the `titre_n°_serie` class name. As it's not a standard `[a-z0-9]` character, it will make it more difficult for anyone, possibly even yourself to reference at a later date.

Comment: I tried also with a "float : left" for my ".model_box" but it did nothing :/

Comment: @Novocaine : thx, you are right, I will remove that.

Comment: @Jacob Lauritzen : The flexbox stuff doens't look very easy to understand. I'm really looking for a basic thing, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: @Novocaine Not true, while it is non-ASCII it is still a valid character (Unicode character) can be used for [CSS identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812072/allowed-characters-for-css-identifiers)

Comment: @HashemQolami I didn't say it was invalid - just more difficult to use.

Comment: @Novocaine `it's not a standard [a-z0-9] character` - you said; Please define the *standard*.

Comment: @HashemQolami the `[a-z0-9]` that I wrote is defining the standard characters in a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add css like

```
.model_box ,.compo_box,.autre_box{display: inline-block;}
.autre_box{margin-right: 0;}
```

Comment: Thanks ^^ After a mix with all the answers I get, I managed to get what I wanted :D

Answer (score 2):

rty this code  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/umlBc)

```
.gros_box{
padding-top : 20px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 50px;
  text-align:center;

/*width: 850px;*/
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;
}

.titre_n°_serie{

padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 10px;
padding-left : 10px;
padding-bottom : 10px;

width: 200px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin:0 auto;

text-align : center;

}

.model_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;
  display:inline-block;

/*width: 350px;*/
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;
}

.compo_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;
  display:inline-block;

/*width: 350px;*/
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;
}

.autre_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;
  display:inline-block;

/*width: 350px;*/
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;
}
```

Comment: When I do your code, it removed me all my box border and the paddings of my "gros_box" and "titre_num_serie" :/

Comment: it means that something is wrong doing .... there is only a sketch in the future you yourself can set the height and width, and even if you want to be taken into account and that the boarders that need to add box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: this solution is suitable for fixed-width layout

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style as follows to achieve your requirements

```
.gros_box {
    padding-top : 20px;
    padding-right : 50px;
    padding-left : 50px;
    padding-bottom : 50px;
    /*width: 850px;*/
    border: 5px solid navy;
    margin: 25px;
}
.titre_n°_serie {
    padding-top : 10px;
    padding-right : 10px;
    padding-left : 10px;
    padding-bottom : 10px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 5px solid navy;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align : center;
}
.model_box, .compo_box, .autre_box {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    height: 300px;
}
.model_box {
    width: 25%;
    border: 5px solid navy;
}
.compo_box {
    width: 30%;
    border: 5px solid navy;
}
.autre_box {
    width: 25%;
    border: 5px solid navy;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/yupzdn42/)**

Comment: I don't know why but my paddings and box border dissapear for "gros_box" and "titre_num_serie" with your code too :/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), you don't have to worry about these box arrangement nav bar and also it is responsive. Work perfectly on all screen size including mobile, Tablets. It will make easier to design any pages.

Comment: I'm using Boostrap but not everywhere because I don't understand all the time how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
.gros_box{
padding-top : 20px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 50px;

/*width: 850px;*/
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;

float:left;
}

.titre_num_serie{

padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 10px;
padding-left : 10px;
padding-bottom : 10px;

width: 200px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin:0 auto;

text-align : center;

}

.model_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;

width: 230px;
height:250px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;
float:left;
}

.compo_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;

width: 230px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;

float:left;
height:250px;
}

.autre_box{
padding-top : 10px;
padding-right : 50px;
padding-left : 50px;
padding-bottom : 15px;

width: 230px;
border: 5px solid navy;
margin: 25px;

height:250px;
float:left;
}
```

use this css