# Regular Expression to Match strings that start with . # and normal

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to identify if the string start with dot, hashtag or none, but i'm doing something wrong, i believe.

```
Selector.match = {
    'id'        : new RegExp('^#(' + identifier + ')' ),
    'class' : new RegExp('^\\.(' + identifier + ')' ),
    'tag'       : new RegExp('^(' + identifier + '|[*])' ),
};

    if (Selector.match['id'].exec(this.selector)) {
        console.log('ID');
        this.result.push(document.getElementById(this.selector));

    } else if (Selector.match['id'].exec(this.selector)) {
        this.result.push(document.getElementsByClassName(this.selector));

    } else if (Selector.match['tag'].exec(this.selector)) {
        this.result.push(document.getElementsByTagName(this.selector));

    }
```

I'm trying to 'emulate' the way that jquery get elements, but is not working because identifier doesn't exist.

Thanks.

Comment: only for learning :B

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to call this via html, etc.?

Comment: this is relevant? i just want make the regular expression works..

Comment: Can't you just look at `selector.charAt(0)` and compare `===` with `"#"` or `"."` etc. Do you really need a RegExp? Of course you may want to coerce `seletor` to a String first, or check that it is a String. You may want to `trim` the string first too.

Comment: regular expression is faster, no? @Xotic750

Comment: No, regular expressions are not very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you an example of what I mentioned in my comments.

Returns a real Array in each case, so Array methods are available on the result.

Because it return an array, the Array is not live list.

```js
var slicer = Array.prototype.slice;

function getElements(selector) {
    var trimmed,
        elements;
    
    if (typeof selector === 'string') {
        trimmed = selector.trim();
        switch (trimmed.charAt(0)) {
            case '.':
                elements = slicer.call(document.getElementsByClassName(trimmed.slice(1)));
                break;
            case '#':
                elements = document.getElementById(trimmed.slice(1));
                if (elements) {
                    elements = [elements];
                } else {
                    elements = [];
                }
                
                break;
            default:
                elements = slicer.call(document.getElementsByTagName(trimmed));
        }
    } else {
        elements = [];
    }
    
    return elements;
}

console.log(getElements());
console.log(getElements('#one'));
console.log(getElements('#two'));
console.log(getElements('.two'));
console.log(getElements('.one'));
console.log(getElements('*'));
console.log(getElements('div'));
console.log(getElements('blah'));
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define identifier.

You can start with something as simple as:

```
var identifier='[A-Za-z0-9_]';
```

but it's a lot more complex.  You can find the details more in depth here:

[Allowed characters for CSS identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812072/allowed-characters-for-css-identifiers)

Also, your second regex comparision is testing for id again where it should be class.

```
} else if (Selector.match['id'].exec(this.selector)) {
        this.result.push(document.getElementsByClassName(this.selector));
```

to

```
} else if (Selector.match['class'].exec(this.selector)) {
        this.result.push(document.getElementsByClassName(this.selector));
```

And in any case, your code will fail on more complex selectors, such as:

- ## myid.class
- .class#id
- .class1.class2
- a.class
- .aa:last-child
- ## myid > p
- ## myid:not(.class)

Also, you should be using `.test` instead of `.exec`. `.exec` will sort of work, because it will return either an array of info if it matches or null if it doesnt' which should satisfy a boolean in the if statement, but `.test` is really what you are looking for.

Of course, you could just replace the entire code with:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(this.selector);
```

which works in all modern browsers (IE 9+, Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.6+, Safari 3.2+)

```js
function getElements(selector)
{
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
console.log(getElements());
console.log(getElements('#one'));
console.log(getElements('#two'));
console.log(getElements('.two'));
console.log(getElements('.one'));
console.log(getElements('*'));
console.log(getElements('div'));
console.log(getElements('blah'));
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: i know.. but first i need pick with just one id, class or tag.. after i want implement more complex selectors @robert