# How to find all numeric classes jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there any way to find all numeric classes with jQuery?

I have elements with the following classes:

```
<div class="placeholder 0 original dropped default-load"></div>
<div class="placeholder 1 original dropped default-load"></div>
<div class="placeholder 2 original dropped default-load"></div>
<div class="placeholder 3 original dropped default-load"></div>
```

But, I'm using jQuery draggable ui. So those placeholders are draggable, and eventualy those numeric classes will be in a random order eg (3, 0, 2, 1), and will no longer match with the `index` if I use the `.each` function.

So basicly, on pageload, the elements will have the order as 0, 1, 2, 3, ... (based on amount of results in the database).

They can mess around and this will result in a random order (0, 3, 2, 1, ...). But there is a default button. With this button they can undo all there actions, and reset the default order.

I tried with the following but this didn't work as the `index` doesn't match with the numeric class if they mess around (which they will obviously will).

```
$(".default").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li.placeholder").each(function (index) {
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).removeClass(index);
        $(this).removeClass("dropped");
        $(this).removeClass("default-load");
        if (!($(this).hasClass("original"))) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
        $(".modal-" + index).remove();
    });
    init(); // Callback
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Numeric classes are a bad idea. Use `data-index="1"` etc. instead. Data attributes are much more appropriate for this.

Comment: Yes, I concluded the same after i noticed the bug. But this would give me alot of debugging work. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Not to mention that `2` is [not a valid css value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2812097/859154)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, you should use `data-*` attribute to store the index. If that is not possible, you can extract the numeric classname from classList.

1. You can use `sort` to sort the elements
2. To extract the numeric classname from element you can use regex, `/\b(\d+)\b/`
3. The sorted list can be then replaced on the unsorted elements

**Demo**

```js
// This will extract the numeric classname
function getNumericClassname(el) {
  return ($(el).attr('class').match(/\b(\d+)\b/) || [])[1];
}

$('#sort').on('click', function() {
  var sortedData = $('.placeholder').sort(function(a, b) {
    return getNumericClassname(a) - getNumericClassname(b);
  });

  $('#container').html(sortedData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="placeholder 0 original dropped default-load">0</div>

  <div class="placeholder 2 original dropped default-load">2</div>

  <div class="placeholder 1 original dropped default-load">1</div>
  <div class="placeholder 3 original dropped default-load">3</div>
</div>

<button id="sort">Sort</button>
```

---

Using `data-index`

```js
$('#sort').on('click', function() {
  var sortedData = $('.placeholder').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data('index') - $(b).data('index');
  });

  $('#container').addClass('sorted').html(sortedData);
});
```

```css
.placeholder {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.sorted .placeholder {
  background: green;
}
button {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="placeholder original dropped default-load" data-index="3">3</div>
  <div class="placeholder original dropped default-load" data-index="0">0</div>
  <div class="placeholder original dropped default-load" data-index="2">2</div>
  <div class="placeholder original dropped default-load" data-index="1">1</div>

</div>

<button id="sort">Sort</button>
```

Comment: Just a remark on your edit: Originaly I just asked for how to find all numeric classes. Not how to find and sort them...

Comment: @JeroenBellemans Aah! And I thought you want to sort them, anyway, I will not update my answer now as it has answered your question and I've put efforts to achieve sorting :)

Comment: I'm very glad for your help, but it was concerning the title you edited. Thanks tho!!

Comment: @JeroenBellemans I realised that it should be the old one, rollbacked

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tushar's answer and following Niet the Dark Absol's comment, here is how you would do it using a data attribute.
If you can, data-* attributes should really be preferred instead of using numerical classes.

```js
var divs = $(".placeholder").filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("data-index") !== undefined;
});

divs.css("background-color", "green");
```

```css
.placeholder {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="placeholder original dropped default-load" data-index=0></div>
<div class="placeholder original dropped default-load" data-index=1></div>
<div class="placeholder original dropped default-load" data-index=2></div>
<div class="placeholder original dropped default-load" data-index=3></div>
<div class="shouldNotBeSelected placeholder"></div>
```