# How to remove style css of div inside the another div?

Tags: html, css, styles

I have a little problem with css.

I have one  with css, which is generated by code inside another . I can't change the css file.

And I need remove this style. Is it possible somehow?

```
<div class="1">

   #Generated by code
   <div class="2" style="xxxxxxxx">
      This text is bold now. Cause of the style. I need normal!
   </div>
   #Generated by code

</div>
```

Is there something I can do??

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you add custom styles either internally or externally? If so, you can always over-qualify inline style rules by declaring the `!important` declaration ad the end of your rule; e.g; `.1 .2 {font-weight: normal !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use javascript ?

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

    <div class="1">

       #Generated by code
       <div class="2" style="xxxxxxxx">
          This text is bold now. Cause of the style. I need normal!
       </div>
       #Generated by code

    </div>

    <script>

function MyFunction 
{
   document.getElementsByClassName("2").style.blabla;
}

    </script>
```

Or even use

```
<style>
.2
{
width:50px;
}
</style>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important` for this:

```
<div class="_1">
    #Generated by code
    <div class="_2" style="font-weight: normal !important;">
        This text is bold now. Cause of the style. I need normal!
    </div>
    #Generated by code
</div>
```

or you can create a new CSS file include it to your template. In your CSS you put something like:

```
._1 > ._2 {
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

> Note that identifiers can't start with numbers, so you have to put a letter or underscore to it, something like `_1` in CSS would it be `._1 { }`. Read about it on this post: [Allowed characters for CSS identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812072/allowed-characters-for-css-identifiers)
>
> According to the comment from @Error404 below: `!important` exception is not necesary on inline styles. As MDN says, Inline styles added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight:bold") always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets and thus can be thought of as having the highest specificity.
>
> Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception. There is also an answer from **@Error404** with more details about this (Below or on top of this answer)

See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o24jww1b/1/

Comment: I can not change the second div. I can only change the first one.

Comment: `!important exception` is not necesary on inline styles. As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types) says, _Inline styles added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight:bold") always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets and thus can be thought of as having the highest specificity._

Comment: Thanks, I have attached your comment in my answer @Error404 :-)

Comment: @C0dekid You are welcome :) but I think you should also add the link to the MDN specification to better clarification.

Comment: So, now i've made a reference to your anser, because it contains extended information about this all :-) @Error404

Answer (score 0):

You can create another file of CSS and try to put a higher [`specificity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types) to the styles applied to your `div`. If you set an `ID` to your `div` and apply your styles from your new CSS stylesheet, it has the highest `specificity`.

Try to avoid the [`!important exception`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) if you can achieve it setting a higher specificity to your new `CSS` styles for that `div`. Using `!important exception` is considered a bad practice as they put in the webpage:

> Using !important is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets.

The problem is that inline styles override all the styles of external stylesheets so you maybe will have to use `!important exception` here.

> Inline styles added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight:bold") always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets and thus can be thought of as having the highest specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript as mentioned before is a good way of achieving your desired behaviour. But according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

```
document.getElementsByClassName()
```

returns an array like structure. So the correct syntax will be

```
document.getElementsByClassName('2')[0].style.fontWeight = 'normal';
```

or to completely remove the style property use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('2')[0].removeAttribute('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with jquery
use this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("._2").css("font-size", "normal");
});
</script>
```