# div with "/" inside, css equivalent?

Tags: html, css, sass

One of my div's names is "N/A (nationwide)", and I have an scss file for css properties. How would I apply css to this div?

neither

```
 .N/A{

}

.(nationwide){

}
```

seem to work.

Comment: what is the html for it ..

Comment: Give it a class and style the class.

Comment: [Escape the special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6592488/901048)

Comment: check [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` character with a backslash, like this:

```
.N\/A{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2812072/3136474) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448981/3136474) about the allowed characters in class names, and you can also check the [Grammar on W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner) that `/` isn't an allowed character in class names.

I'm not aware of any Sass rule that allows it.